# Excel VBA Double Addition Error

Tags: excel, double, addition, vba

I'm having a hard time explaining this one.  The following function is being used as a worksheet formula.  A value of "empty" simply means that the cell was empty and, therefore, there is no value.  Given the values {empty, empty, 0.8, 0.2}, the following function is *sometimes* returning off the wall values like 5.55111512312578E-17.  In the debugger, it looks like everything is correct until the last value in the ParamArray (in this case 0.2) is processed.  Any thoughts?

```
   Private Function getOvertimeEP(ParamArray epAllocations() As Variant)
        Dim overtimeEP As Double
        overtimeEP = -1

        For Each nextVal In epAllocations
            overtimeEP = overtimeEP + nextVal
        Next

        If overtimeEP < 0 Then
            overtimeEP = 0
        End If

        getOvertimeEP = overtimeEP
    End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is the result of [floating point accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).  Even if your first two values are 0 and 0, it will still have the same result.  So will {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}.

Round it to some reasonable number of decimal places before returning it and call it a day.