# Inaccurate calculations in Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel VBA Double Addition Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207453/excel-vba-double-addition-error)

I have a very simple VBA macro in Excel that calculates the difference between two numbers. When I try to calculate the difference between 0.7 and 0.65 it returns 4.99999999999999E-02. Why?

Here's my function:

```
Public Function Diff(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
    Diff = x - y
    Debug.Print Diff
End Function
```

Here's what I see in the 'Immediate' window:

```
4.99999999999999E-02
```

To replicate this 'bug' you can type "?0.7-0.65" in the Immediate window and see what you get in return.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3207453/698590)

Comment: This may be helpful :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136860/how-to-check-dependencies-of-floats/9136907#9136907

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floating point representations are only approximations - it is not possible to store arbitrary decimal fractions in binary. Google for "floating point error" for some background and examples, or see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) article on Floating Point